# Using Aamazon SP-API to create Web-hooks to get Order changes

Tags: c#, notifications, webhooks, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am in the process of changing how our company processes orders from Amazon.  Currently we use SP-API methods (GetOrders) to get unshipped orders and from that list, get the PPE data using a restricted token.

The issue is that as our company has grown, we are hitting more and more throttling as orders have grown, when we need to take down our servers for routine maintenance, or if we are down for any period of time.  Investigating I discovered that Amazon has now added ORDER_STATUS_CHANGE to it's notification system.  I am trying to find any *understandable* information on how to implement this process.

From what I get from Amazon they talk about setting up subscriptions, queues and then POST a webhook dstination, but when I did other reseach I got something as simple as

```
            // Create the request body
        string requestBody = $"{{\"name\": \"{destinationName}\", \"resourceSpecification\": {{\"resourceType\": \"orders\", \"eventTypes\": [\"ORDER_COMPLETED\"]}}, \"destinationResource\": {{\"intendedState\": \"ACTIVE\", \"resourceType\": \"URL\", \"value\": \"{url}\"}}}}";

        // Send the API request to register the destination
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync($"/notifications/v1/destinations?marketplaceIds={marketplaceId}&sellerId={sellerId}", new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

I know I need to have a reciever web service (thus the URL destination), and I can work through the body Json, but my basic question is....

Has anyone set up, using c#, a webhook for order status change using SP-API (Notifications) and is there basic example of how the receiver web service should be coded?  (In all my career I have not done a lot of HTTP raw communication programming).

Just for fun this is one example I got from Assistant (I may try it, but it has lied to me before):

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Your Selling Partner API endpoint
            string endpoint = "https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com";

            // Your access token
            string accessToken = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";

            // Your seller ID
            string sellerId = "YOUR_SELLER_ID";

            // Your marketplace ID
            string marketplaceId = "YOUR_MARKETPLACE_ID";

            // The URL of your webhook listener
            string url = "YOUR_WEBHOOK_URL";

            // The name of your destination
            string destinationName = "YOUR_DESTINATION_NAME";

            // Create an HttpClient object
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            // Set the base address of the HttpClient object
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(endpoint);

            // Set the default request headers of the HttpClient object
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // Create the request body
            string requestBody = $"{{\"name\": \"{destinationName}\", \"resourceSpecification\": {{\"resourceType\": \"orders\", \"eventTypes\": [\"ORDER_COMPLETED\"]}}, \"destinationResource\": {{\"intendedState\": \"ACTIVE\", \"resourceType\": \"URL\", \"value\": \"{url}\"}}}}";

            // Send the API request to register the destination
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync($"/notifications/v1/destinations?marketplaceIds={marketplaceId}&sellerId={sellerId}", new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            // Read the response content as a string
            string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Check the response status code
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Webhook has been registered successfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to register webhook. Status code: {response.StatusCode}. Error message: {responseContent}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to cluster your server(s) so when you take down one server you can still process orders : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/clusters.html?force_isolation=true.  Also see : https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/notifications-api-v1-use-case-guide?force_isolation=true